# SLURM "srun module load" command exits with error

Tags: slurm

I am using a slurm cluster with Lmod. I have 2 nodes and I want to load a module on both the nodes. When I run the command

`srun -n2 module load python/3.8.10` I receive `slurmstepd: error: execve(): module: No such file or directory`. Why is it not running the `module load` command? It is instead searching for a file with name `module`. How do I get this to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `module` command is a shell function, so it doesn't work like a regular command, hence `No such file or directory`. (Try `which module` and `type module` and you'll see what I mean).

You don't need to use `srun` to execute `module` commands in any case, just do `module load python/3.8.10` in your submit script before running your code (with `srun`) and the new environment will be propagated to all nodes in the allocation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
But how should we do if we need "module load" inside the script that submitted to Slurm ?